# Call many python functions from a module by looping through a list of function names and making them variables

Tags: python, string, function, loops, variables

I have three similar functions in tld_list.py. I am working out of mainBase.py file.

I am trying to create a variable string which will call the appropriate function by looping through the list of all functions. My code reads from a list of function names, iterates through the list and running the function on each iteration. Each function returns 10 pieces of information from separate websites

I have tried 2 variations annotated as Option A and Option B below

```
# This is mainBase.py

import tld_list           # I use this in conjunction with Option A
from tld_list import *    # I use this with Option B

functionList = ["functionA", "functionB", "functionC"]
tldIterator = 0
while tldIterator < len(functionList):
    # This will determine which function is called first
    # In the first case, the function is functionA
    currentFunction = str(functionList[tldIterator])
```

Option A

```
    currentFunction = "tld_list." + currentFunction
    websiteName = currentFunction(x, y)
    print(websiteName[1]
    print(websiteName[2]
    ...
    print(websiteName[10]
```

Option B

```
    websiteName = currentFunction(x, y)
    print(websiteName[1]
    print(websiteName[2]
    ...
    print(websiteName[10]
```

Even though it is not seen, I continue to loop through the iteration by ending each loop with `tldIterator += 1`

Both options fail for the same reason stating `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

I am wondering what I am doing wrong, or if it is even possible to call a function in a loop with a variable

Comment: You don't have a list of functions, you have a list of strings. Why don't you just create a list of functions?

Comment: What would a list of functions look like? Can you provide the syntax and example?

Comment: Functions are just objects, like any other: `[functionA, functionB, functionC]`

Comment: Your comments and the examples below all made sense when I tried them. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the function names but what you really want are the function objects bound to those names in `tld_list`. Since function names are attributes of the module, `getattr` does the job. Also, it seems like list iteration rather than keeping track of your own `tldIterator` index would suffice.

```
import tld_list

function_names = ["functionA", "functionB", "functionC"]
functions = [getattr(tld_list, name) for name in function_names]
for fctn in functions:
    website_name = fctn(x,y)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dictionary to provide a name to function conversion:

```
def funcA(...): pass
def funcB(...): pass
def funcC(...): pass

func_find = {"Huey": funcA, "Dewey": funcB, "Louie": FuncC}
```

Then you can call them, e.g.

```
result = func_find["Huey"](...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid this type of code. Try using if's, or references instead. But you can try:

```
websiteName = exec('{}(x, y)'.format(currentFunction))
```